# Querying Cache from Compute Job

Tags: ignite

Is it possible to Query Ignite Cache from within a Compute Job in Apache Ignite? Can someone point me to any existing examples

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, an answer is posted here: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/newbie-question-how-best-to-pass-Ignite-to-a-ComputeJob-td503.html, using InstanceResource an instance of Ignite can be accessed.